# Get data from another model laravel-api-generator

Tags: laravel

I am using https://github.com/mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator

I would like to get data from another model. When inserting a post pick the category data.

**PostController.php**

```
class PostController extends AppBaseController
{

    /** @var  PostRepository */
    private $postRepository;

    /** @var  CategoriesRepository */
    private $categoriesRepository;

    function __construct(PostRepository $postRepo, CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepo)
    {
        $this->postRepository = $postRepo;
        $this->categoriesRepository = $categoriesRepo;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the Post.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = $this->postRepository->paginate(10);
        $categories = $this->categoriesRepository->all('id', 'desc')->get();

        return view('posts.index')
            ->with('posts', $posts)
            ->with('categories', $categories);
    }
```

**fields.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', Categories::lists('name', 'id'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should make the list in controller and pass it to the view.

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = $this->postRepository->paginate(10);
        $categories = $this->categoriesRepository->all('id', 'desc')->get();
        $categoryList = [ '' => '--select--' ] + $categories->lists('name', 'id'); 
        return view('posts.index')
            ->with('posts', $posts)
            ->with('categories', $categories)
            ->with('categoryList', $categoryList);
    }
```

And use this variable to generate the select.

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', $categoryList, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [ViewComposers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers) and pass category list array in fields.blade.php. so it will not affect directly your templates or generator.

Whenever you have a requirement where you always have to pass fields of another model in any view, I think you should use view composer.

Comment: no difference in just passing the category list array to current blade file and using view composers. This just adds additional code which may not be reusable